# What kind of iterators supports random access but not contiguous storage in C++?

Tags: c++11, iterator, categories, contiguous

I saw that there is a new iterator since C++17,below listed by a screenshot in cppreference. I was a lot confused. What kind of iterators is  random access but not contiguous storage in C++?? otherwise, the ContiguousIterator is not powerful than  RandomAccessIterator ? right?

[image]

And then the link [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)

Comment: Did you at least *look* at your question's preview? "enter image description here"...

Comment: so sorry. I was not carefully press the Enter key and post it immediately.  I will take care it next.

Comment: You can always [edit] the Q

Comment: I am a beginner here... I will do it best next.

Answer (score 4):

One non-contiguous container with random-access iterators is [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). Quoting the cppreference site:

> As opposed to `std::vector`, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays.
>
> The complexity (efficiency) of common operations on deques is as follows:
>
> - Random access - constant *O(1)*
> - Insertion or removal of elements at the end or beginning - constant *O(1)*
> - Insertion or removal of elements - linear *O(n)*

Comment: oh,yeah. I saw it. thx.  Aside from the std::deque. and any else ?

Comment: Also, `vector<bool>`.

Comment: @T.C. The iterator of `vector<bool>` doesn’t even satisfy [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator), because `vector<bool>::iterator::reference` is not `bool&` or `const bool&`.